# Dependency Resolution issue when setting up <Build> properties

Tags: java, spring, maven

I am developing Hibernate , Spring application. I need to create a executable jar with maven to execute the

application. To do this I am defining the main class com.sample.App. My maven version is 3.2.3. JDK

is 1_6_20.  I am getting below error when i add  tag  the POM.xml. Please help me on What

could be the dependency am I missing ?

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.2.3 or one of it
s dependencies could

not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:m
aven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.2.3 in

https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cache
d in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update i
nterval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.mkyong.common</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringExample</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>

    <!-- JUnit testing framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring AOP dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate annotation -->
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Hibernate library dependecy end -->
      </dependencies>

         <build>

            <finalName>cc-masker</finalName>
            <plugins>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.6</source>
                  <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                      <mainClass>com.mkyong.common.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.mkyong.common.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>make-my-jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </execution>
                </executions>
              </plugin>
            </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `maven-compiler-plugin` version 3.2.3, yet. As of September 2014, the [current version](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) is 3.1.

Maven plugins don't track the version of the main Maven executable; in general you'll need to see what the latest version of each plugin is.

Note that *each* plugin is versioned separately so, for example, `maven-jar-plugin` is currently on 2.5.

Comment: Thanks, changed the version. [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.1 or one of its depen
dencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ja
r-plugin:jar:3.1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
 repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cen
tral has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugi
ns:maven-jar-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be

Comment: I addedd   <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>3.1</version>
</dependency> too